How can I represent cloud cover and rain in an attractive way for an e-paper weather HUD?
I am writing an application to display weather information on an 800x600 pixel e-paper display. The weather API I'm using gives information about cloud cover and rainfall for every minute of the next hour, and every hour of the next two days. It's a lot of useful information, and I'd like to present it in a way that's informative and attractive. I have made some progress, but I think my display still isn't that attractive. Perhaps someone can offer advice.
The top half of the display shows the cloud cover and rainfall.

The clouds are represented by the symmetric double line at the top. Fat sections show more cloud cover. Vertical bars below the clouds represent rainfall. Start and end times for periods of rain are automatically labelled. Horizontal black bars show the days, and contain white bars to show the daylight hours.
The first 60 bars are thin, showing every minute for the next hour. The other 48 fatter bars show every hour. But on the screen it's hard to see the transition between the minutes and hours sections. Here I've tried drawin a thin grey line to mark the transition, but it doesn't look good.

My main problem is that he clouds don't look very nice. My second problem is that it's hard to see the difference between minutes and hours.
Can anyone suggest a better way to represent this information?

Do bars below the reference line indicate negative values? If not, please do not break convention. My suggestion will be to stick to easier and more widely understood chart types. Since 'time' is a continuous variable, you can opt for line chart instead of bar chart.

@Ren - They do not represent negative rain. Originally, I had them the usual way up, but I thought that maybe it would make sense to have them come down as if they were the rain coming down from the clouds above. Although it does break convention, I think it's fairly intuitive this way up.

As we're on a UX website, I'd like to take a few steps back and approach it from the UX perspective before jumping to UI.


My second problem is that it's hard to see the difference between minutes and hours.


Do you need the minute resolution of rainfall (and cloud coverage)?
Does your data provider's past accuracy warrant having a minute resolution? Or would you be better off with much lower resolution?
Do you recall seeing a bar chart that changes the resolution abruptly like this, from minute to hour resolution? If so, was that chart easy to understand?

You're the only one who can answer those questions. Sadly, this isn't a perfect place to facilitate a real-time discussion, so the rest of my answer will be based off my suspicion: I believe the answers will lean towards "no" for all three.
Looking at the minute-part, I find it hard to believe that your data provider is able to predict the exact minute the rain will start and stop. Even if it worked perfectly and they're 100% accurate down to the minute - did that precision and accuracy help you in any way?
I'm not trying to argument against the entire idea, but since we're on UX stack exchange, it's good to question the initial assumptions. This can help understand the fundamental issues that your design is supposed to tackle. I can relate to "I want it, and I think it looks neat" argument, but I believe it's better to iteratively find a solution that actually solves the problem.

Why is there no scale for the Y-axis?

If you work off a rough assumption that "full bar == some value of rain" and don't need a labeled Y axis because you just estimate the value by looking at it, then how will you deal with outliers? If you only estimate the rough value, then maybe it isn't really needed to have minute resolution?


My main problem is that he clouds don't look very nice.

I'm assuming that the code works by finding the biggest value and scaling the rest of the cloud coverage chart to fill the predefined height. This creates a problem, though: this chart is no longer glanceable, and datasets "1 1 5 10%" and "10 10 50 100%" will display the same way.
I would suggest making the line chart always scale with 100% as the max, so it's immediately obvious how high the values really are. If you need an even stronger signal and play with the UI, you could use pattern fills with variable fill rate under the line (like ░░▒▒▓▓██). This would be just an additional touch, not really needed since the line's height would be enough of a signal.

To sum up, my suggestions would be:

Remove the high-resolution part completely. It makes the charts confusing to read (Why are those bars thinner? Why is there a vertical line? Does the high resolution part also apply to cloud coverage?), and may not provide data that's really useful.
Flip the rain chart upside down, like others have suggested. Even if the rain falls from above, it ultimately doesn't hang like icicles, but accumulates upwards on the ground (and that's what the rain gauges measure in mm).
Add Y axis with values and horizontal lines to make the values easy to read and easily deal with rain outliers.
Scale the cloud chart to show the entire 0-100% range all the time. Add Y axis with the scale and draw a horizontal line at 50/100%, or maybe at 25/50/75/100%. Display only one data line, without mirroring it to make a cloud shape. Maybe add a dithered fill, like Unicode block elements light/medium/dark shade.


Finally, I recommend looking at the Practical Charts books (I'm not affiliated, just found the author's work very useful).

Thank you for this answer. It's really thoughtful and helpful. I do like the idea of questioning basic assumptions. At the risk of starting a protracted discussion, let me answer a couple of your points just to clarify.


I believe that the minute data is both accurate and useful. It's accurate because it's calculated for a specific GPS coordinate from the rain radar and wind velocity. It's very useful for a cyclist (like myself) to know if the rain is going to stop in 10 minutes (therefore wait and cycle) or in 1 hour, therefore take the train and an umbrella.



Past accuracy has shown this prediction to be accurate. Have you ever had the pleasure of using the Dark Skies app (now owned by Apple I think). It would literally watch the rain coming or going from your exact location and make accurate predictions.



I have never seen a bar chart change scale, and I realise that it makes the presentation less intuitive. But If I decide that I do want to show it, I'm not sure of another way to represent the data.



No scale on the Y-axis for the same reason that there's no scale on the rain icons on most weather maps. Usually you'll see a cloud with one or two or three drops. What's the scale?  We intuitively understand that it means a little, a medium amount or a lot of rain.


Thank you for the link to Practical Charts. I will take a look. And thank you for taking the time to write a through and thoughtful answer.

I'm glad it was helpful! I see how having precise data can be useful in this case. I have used DarkSky's API and mourned its passing; it was accurate indeed. Do you recommend a data provider with comparable quality?

I would explore some ASCII representation
      __   _
    _(  )_( )_
   (_   _    _)
  / /(_) (__)
 / / / / / /
/ / / / / /

Source asciiart
       _
     _( )_          _      
   _(     )_      _( )_
  (_________)   _(     )_
    \  \  \    (_________)
      \  \       \  \  \
                   \  \

Source ascii.co.uk

Source wttr.in

Thank you for this answer. Luckly, I can display graphics so I don't really need ASCII. Also, I'm not sure how this solves my specific problem?

Well, your question is "How can I represent cloud cover and rain in an attractive way for an e-paper" and this is my answer. If your question is different, perhaps you should rephrase the statement.

I'm not sure where the 60 minute and 48 hour rain data is represented in this image.
